# How does "Pointer to Function" Syntax Work in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

How (*ptr_fun1)(10) and ptr_fun1(10) are same in the below code

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun1(int a)
{
     printf("It is %d\n",a);
}
int main()
{
  void (*ptr_fun1)(int);
  ptr_fun1 = fun1;
/*
   ex-
        ptr_fun1    fun1    
        +----+      +-----+
        +1000+      +code +
        +----+      +-----+
         1234        1000
        fun1(10); <=> ptr_fun1(10); //how
*/
  printf("%d\n%d",ptr_fun1(10),(*ptr_fun1)(20));
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
10
20
```

Can some one please explain how it works.

Comment: When not used in a function call or as an operand for the address-of operator `&`, a function name is a pointer to the function. This means that if `f` is a function, `f` and `&f` are the same thing.

Comment: The function that you include (fun1) is not a function. It does not return anything. Try changing from void to return a value.

Comment: @dash-o: The C standard calls these functions regardless of whether they return a value.

Comment: The code, as included in the question, fail to compile because of the type issue: t3.c: In function ‘main’: t3.c:19:19: error: invalid use of void expression printf("%d\n%d",ptr_fun1(10),(*ptr_fun1)(20));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for declaring (and using) function pointers in `C` (and `C++`) is one of the most puzzling aspects of the language for beginners. I shall try to explain a little, here.

First, let's consider pointers to 'simple' types (we'll take the 'int' type as an example). In this case, declaring a variable of the type is trivial: `int N;` Also, declaring a pointer to an `int` is also trivial: `int *pN;`We can interpret this second declaration in terms of 'evaluating' the '*' operator, which means "get the object that resides at the given address." So, in `int *pN` we are declaring that "the object that lies at the address "pN" is an `int`.

For functions, this is not so simple! Take a case of a function that takes an `int` as its (only) argument and returns an `int` value: `int IFunc(int arg);`. This is also very straightforward.

But how could we declare a pointer to such a function? We ***cannot*** simply apply the same logic as for the 'simple' types (by preceding with a `*` operator), like this:

```
int *pIFunc(int arg);
```

Because this would declare a **function** that takes an `int` arg and returns a **pointer to an int**.

So, the early implementors of the `C` language had to come up with something better - and completely unambiguous. So they decided to use the syntax of putting the "*NAME" section in parentheses, to isolate that 'dereference' operation from the function's definition:

```
int (*pIFunc)(int arg);
```

So, when faced with anything that looks remotely like this: `< typename > (*Name1)(...);` (where < typename > is any allowable C-type, like `int`, `void`, `double`, or even 'compound' types such as `int*`, and the "..." inside the second set of brackets can be either empty or a list of other 'types'), recognize it as a declaration of a function pointer (or as dereferencing a function pointer). To get the underlying function 'signature' (or invocation), just remove the first set of brackets and the contained `*`. So, for:

```
(*ptr_fun1)(20)
```

you can read:

```
ptr_fun1(20)
```

And, for:

```
void (*ptr_fun1)(int);
```

you can see that `ptr_fun` has the following signature:

```
void ptr_fun1(int);
```

I hope this makes things a bit clearer. Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanations.